# Phone Call Functionality for Bixby Capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Does anyone know or have a clue on implementing a phone call functionality in a Bixby capsule. That is for example, like from the Yelp capsule, a user presses a 'Call Business' button at the bottom and the capsule initiates a phone call with the business.

I have extensively been looking at the Developer's Guide (Contact library):

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.contact

But it seems like they don't have an action call for a phone call.

```
compound-card {
          content {
            single-line {
              image {
                url("../assets/ic_btn_call.png")
              }
              spacer
              text {
                value ("Call #{value(phoneNumber)}")
                style(Title_XS)
              }
            }
          }
          on-click {
            intent {
              // goal : Call action not implemented
              value {
                $expr (phoneNumber)
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution:

Although it is not documented, use app-launch to take advantage of Android's built-in href

1. add the following code in your view file

```
  app-launch {
    payload-uri ("tel: 1-800-726-7864") // samsung number
  }
```

2. do a private submission and load revision number to your phone.
3. get to the view with `app-launch`, and you will be re-direct to phone-call with the number.
4. you need to confirm the call by press the green dial icon.

Answer (score 1):

Some of Bixby's early adopters helped us explore and develop new features. As a part of this partnership, they have access to newer features.

The ability to make a call is one such feature which is being developed comprehensively and will soon be available to all of our developer community!

Please follow this feature request https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360029568074-Allow-access-to-phone-dialer for updates on release date and to share your comments or thoughts.